# codesign_allocate: file not in an order that can be processed (code signature data out of place)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, codesign

I have an iOS app ipa that I need to resign. After unziping the ipa and replacing the mobileprovisioning profile, I attempt to resign the app using the codesign command:

```
codesign -i "edu.eduname.appname" -f -s "iPhone Distribution: EDU University (XXXXXXXX)"  "Payload/Appname.app"
```

The error I get is:

```
codesign_allocate: file not in an order that can be processed (code signature data out of place)
```

This is the full output:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/**codesign_allocate: file not in an order that can be processed (code signature data out of place)**: /build/Payload/Appname.app/Appname (for architecture armv7)
  Payload/Appname.app: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used

This is an existing app and this has worked several times in the past just a year ago the latest. It's built in Unity if that makes a difference. I tried to recreate it by building a sample Unity app but I was able to resign that with no problem.

I'm using xcode 9.2. I also tried xcode 9.3 beta and 8.3 tools but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by using a newly built ipa from the developer so this is probably due to a corrupt file in the original. If you have this problem, try rebuilding the ipa before resigning.